# Matlab visualization of video

Tags: matlab, video, callback

I have a video file that I need to visualize in Matlab. From this file, I extract down-sampled thumbnails and merge them into a single image. This image is displayed using `imshow` command and gives the overview of the whole video.

I would like click (or hover) by mouse over any thumbnail and automatically extract from the video full sized version and display it in new figure.

What functions I need to implement such a functionality?

Comment: Have you checked the `VideoReader` class http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreaderclass.html?

Answer (score 0):

Roughly:

1. Connect to your video file using a `VideoReader` object.
2. Get the `NumberOfFrames` property of the `VideoReader` object.
3. Use the `read` method of the `VideoReader` object to read in frames.
4. Loop from 1 to `NumberOfFrames`, and read in each frame.
5. Having read in each frame, store it in the `k`th plane of an M-by-N-by-3-by-K array, where K is the number of frames. (the 3 is if your video is RGB - it would be 1 if grayscale).
6. Also, resize each frame to a thumbnail using the function `imresize`, and store it in the `k`th plane of an m-by-n-by-3-by-K array, where m < M and n < N.
7. Once stored in this form, display the results in a figure using the command `montage`, which will lay all the thumbnails out nicely for you in a grid.
8. Add a callback to the figure that fires when you click on the image. The callback should get the current mouse position (at the time of the click), determine which frame was clicked on, and create a new figure which displays the corresponding plane from the unresized array.

Does that sound possible?